# Error reported by SoundManager

Tags: java, android, soundpool

Got a force close in my app reporting:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: int[] cannot be cast to java.lang.ref.WeakReference
>   at android.media.SoundPool.postEventFromNative(SoundPool.java:466)
>   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

Soundpool is wrapped by a Soundmanager class I created which is used statically, i.e.:

```
    SoundManager.getInstance();
    SoundManager.initSounds(this, mApp.Sound(), mApp.Voice());
    SoundManager.loadSounds();
```

...

```
SoundManager.playSound(SoundManager.SNDGAMEOVER, 1);
```

...

The error occurred between my main activity and another activity - not sure if it was while one instance of the second activity was closing or was opening.  Its difficult to debug because its intermittent.  Has anyone else run in to similar problems?